# format date as mm/dd/yyyy text

Tags: excel, date, text, concatenation

Once a date in the "mm/dd/yyyy" format has been concatenated with a space and with text (e.g. "05/03/2015 Summary Report"), how could you copy this concatenated cell into another cell AS TEXT, but without the date turning into "42127 Summary Report?"

Comment: Since you are using the term *cell*, are you asking an Excel question? You didn't say or tag it in your question.

Comment: Erm, first of all: What language are we talking about? Or what application? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 3):

=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy")," Summary Report")

Where A1 is your cell with the date.